# How to grab a piece of data which has a different xpath on different webpages?

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, web-crawler

So I am trying to grab a piece of data that is displayed in a different xpath on different pages.

if you will see the xpath of the IPA pronunction on wiktionary... https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/foo you will see that the xpath is

```
//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/ul[1]/li[1]/span[4]
```

but if I got to another word, like https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bar then the xpath would be

```
//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/ul[1]/li[2]/span[5]
```

I cannot think of any way to reconcile these, is there something that I am missing?

Comment: The xpath is the same in both pages. The problem is you are selecting different languages. In the first page you get British English (UK) whereas in the second is American English (US).

Comment: You need to ask yourself "how would I, as a human being, tell someone else how to find the bit of content I am interested in, in any page?". Then translate that into XPath.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is simple. Never let a tool write any XPath for you. All tools get it wrong.

Look at the document's HTML source and write the appropriate XPath it yourself.

```
var result = document.evaluate("//*[@class = 'IPA']", document),
    elem;

while (elem = result.iterateNext()) { 
    console.log(elem);
}
```

The above shows the simplest variant. It selects two occurrences of `<span class="IPA">` on https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/foo and quite a few more on https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bar.

Use a more specific expression to narrow down the results.